# Why does getting the class member variable address at compile time result in C2327 and C2065?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I have the following chunk of code which "works" in a simple, newly created hello world VS2017 project, and in another app we have, but for some reason I cannot identify, it doesn't "work" when I port it to the current app I'm working on.

```
/**
 * This can be used to associate a class variable to a type and a string in order
 *  to load it easily from XML or JSON.
 */
template<typename Class, typename T>
struct Property {
  constexpr Property( T Class::*aMember, const char* aName )
    : member { aMember }, name { aName } {}

  using Type = T;
  using ClassType = Class;

  T Class::*member;
  const char* name;
};

struct MajorPaine
{
  int mInt;

  // All errors are "spammed" by the following line:
  static constexpr auto perp = Property<MajorPaine, decltype(MajorPaine::mInt)>{ 
    &MajorPaine::mInt, "int" };
};
```

When I compile this code, I get those errors (compiled with Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.16.27034 for x86):

```
error C2327: 'MajorPaine::mInt': is not a type name, static, or enumerator
error C2065: 'mInt': undeclared identifier
fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
```

What could be the reason for the errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question to help folks avoid spending hours on this (and my future self).

---

tldr: The compiler flag `/permissive-` was not set. Setting it did fix it.

According to the [help page for the /permissive- flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=msvc-150),

> [...] The compiler also implements more of the requirements for two-phase name look-up. When the /permissive- option is set, the compiler parses function and class template definitions, and identifies dependent and non-dependent names used in the templates. [...]

So I assume that both errors stem from the fact that the compiler did a single pass at reading the struct, and did not know *yet* that `mInt` did actually exist. Allowing the compiler to do two phases allows it to see the member and actually use it.

It's worth noting that "*[...] By default, the /permissive- option is set in new projects created by Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5 and later versions.  [...]*". This is explains why it was working fine in a newly created VS project, and in the previous project I worked on, but not on the my current project (because it was created a while ago).